# IL2CPP Vector.Dot inconsistency

Tags: unity, il2cpp

I get inconsistent results when I run this code as standalone Windows on Mono and IL2CPP backends.

```
var a = new Vector3(-1.26998901f, 0, -0.849998474f);
var b = new Vector3(20.0799999f, -1, 164.580002f);
var dot = Vector3.Dot(a, b);
var mydot = (float) ((double) a.x * (double) b.x + (double) a.y * (double) b.y + (double) a.z * (double) b.z);
```

```
+-------+----------------+-------------+
|       | Mono or Editor |   IL2CPP    |
+-------+----------------+-------------+
| dot   | -165.394135    | -165.394119 |
| mydot | -165.394135    | -165.394135 |
+-------+----------------+-------------+
```

Take a look at the `dot` result on IL2CPP backend in the table above.

My `mydot` implementation should be equivalent to `Vector3.Dot(Vector3, Vector3)` according to dotPeek in Rider.

Decompiled Vector3.Dot(Vector3, Vector3)

```
/// <summary>
///   <para>Dot Product of two vectors.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="lhs"></param>
/// <param name="rhs"></param>
public static float Dot(Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs)
{
  return (float) ((double) lhs.x * (double) rhs.x + (double) lhs.y * (double) rhs.y + (double) lhs.z * (double) rhs.z);
}
```

Unity version: `2018.4.12f1`

What causes `Vector3.Dot(Vector3, Vector3)` to give a different result on IL2CPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the IL2CPP output of the `Vector3.Dot` method:

```
IL2CPP_EXTERN_C IL2CPP_METHOD_ATTR float Vector3_Dot_m0C530E1C51278DE28B77906D56356506232272C1 (Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  ___lhs0, Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  ___rhs1, const RuntimeMethod* method)
{
    float V_0 = 0.0f;
    {
        float L_0 = (&___lhs0)->get_x_2();
        float L_1 = (&___rhs1)->get_x_2();
        float L_2 = (&___lhs0)->get_y_3();
        float L_3 = (&___rhs1)->get_y_3();
        float L_4 = (&___lhs0)->get_z_4();
        float L_5 = (&___rhs1)->get_z_4();
        V_0 = ((float)il2cpp_codegen_add((float)((float)il2cpp_codegen_add((float)((float)il2cpp_codegen_multiply((float)L_0, (float)L_1)), (float)((float)il2cpp_codegen_multiply((float)L_2, (float)L_3)))), (float)((float)il2cpp_codegen_multiply((float)L_4, (float)L_5))));
        goto IL_0036;
    }

IL_0036:
    {
        float L_6 = V_0;
        return L_6;
    }
}
```

Note that it does nothing related to casting to doubles. It is unclear why, but the IL2CPP version of `Vector3.Dot` does not match the Mono implementation in that respect. On the other hand, the mydot version compiles to this:

```
    // var mydot = (float)((double)a.x * (double)b.x + (double)a.y * (double)b.y + (double)a.z * (double)b.z);
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_12 = V_0;
    float L_13 = L_12.get_x_2();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_14 = V_1;
    float L_15 = L_14.get_x_2();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_16 = V_0;
    float L_17 = L_16.get_y_3();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_18 = V_1;
    float L_19 = L_18.get_y_3();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_20 = V_0;
    float L_21 = L_20.get_z_4();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_22 = V_1;
    float L_23 = L_22.get_z_4();
    V_3 = (((float)((float)(float)((double)il2cpp_codegen_add((double)((double)il2cpp_codegen_add((double)((double)il2cpp_codegen_multiply((double)(((double)((double)(double)L_13))), (double)(((double)((double)(double)L_15))))), (double)((double)il2cpp_codegen_multiply((double)(((double)((double)(double)L_17))), (double)(((double)((double)(double)L_19))))))), (double)((double)il2cpp_codegen_multiply((double)(((double)((double)(double)L_21))), (double)(((double)((double)(double)L_23))))))))));
```

That's a lot of casts, and definitely makes sure we are using doubles.

This is what it looks like when you remove the explicit double casting:

```
    // var mydot = a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_24 = V_0;
    float L_25 = L_24.get_x_2();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_26 = V_1;
    float L_27 = L_26.get_x_2();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_28 = V_0;
    float L_29 = L_28.get_y_3();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_30 = V_1;
    float L_31 = L_30.get_y_3();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_32 = V_0;
    float L_33 = L_32.get_z_4();
    Vector3_tDCF05E21F632FE2BA260C06E0D10CA81513E6720  L_34 = V_1;
    float L_35 = L_34.get_z_4();
    V_4 = ((float)il2cpp_codegen_add((float)((float)il2cpp_codegen_add((float)((float)il2cpp_codegen_multiply((float)L_25, (float)L_27)), (float)((float)il2cpp_codegen_multiply((float)L_29, (float)L_31)))), (float)((float)il2cpp_codegen_multiply((float)L_33, (float)L_35))));
```

I don't know *why* the `Vector3.Dot` implementation is different between IL2CPP and Mono (perhaps for performance?), but it is different, and there is the reason for your discrepancy anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how did you get the decompiled IL2CPP code?

Comment: @ElasticSea Assuming you are targeting Windows when building, if you build a Visual Studio project instead of building the .exe directly from Unity, you will be able to see the IL2CPP source when you open the project in Visual Studio.